# How to redirect a request to another jsp page/view

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying to create a Employee list creation. In that to create a employee i use service. after creating i need to redirect to the students list page. My sample code is given below by this, the last added item is getting duplicated for each refresh of the page. Please advice!

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/students", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView students() {

        List<Student> students=studentService.getAllStudents();
        ModelAndView view=new ModelAndView();
        view.addObject("objects", students);
        view.setViewName("students");
        return view;
    }


@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") @Validated Student student, BindingResult bindingResult, 
            ModelMap model) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            return new ModelAndView("numberformat", null);
        }

        model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
        model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
        model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

        studentService.createStudent(student);
//      return new ModelAndView("result", model) ;
        return students();
    }
```

Students.jsp

```
        <tr>
            <td><b>ID</b></td>
            <td><b>Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Age</b></td>
            <td><b>Date of Joining</b></td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="o" items="${objects}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${o.id}" /></td>
                <td>
                <a
                    href="<c:url value="result">   

                            <c:param name="studId" value="${o.id}"/>   
                        </c:url>   
                    "><c:out value="${o.name}"/></a>
                </td>
                <td><c:out value="${o.age}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${o.doj}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>

    </table>
</c:if>
```

Student.jsp

```
<body>
    <h2>Employee Information</h2>
<form method="POST" action="/HelloWorld/addStudent">

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="age">Age</label></td>
            <td><input type="number" name= "age" /></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- <tr>
            <td><label for="id">id</label></td>
            <td><input type="number" name= "id" /></td>
        </tr> -->
        <tr>
            <td><label for="doj">Date of Joining</label></td>
            <td><input type="date" name= "doj" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I think the line return students();  in addStudent function causes the problem. Is there any way to return to the students page after adding a student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") @Validated Student student, BindingResult bindingResult, 
        ModelMap model) {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        return new ModelAndView("numberformat", null);
    }

    model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
    model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
    model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

    studentService.createStudent(student);

    return "redirect:students";
}
```

The last line will make Spring return an HTTP 302 to the browser which will then perform a GET to the students URL

Comment: Great :). Good to hear that!

Comment: One more question regarding this. While redirecting using the "redirect" in url, the last updated students details are showing. Can you please advise why ?

Comment: All students are read from the database since students() is called and therefore all the changes show

Comment: The students name are shown as link to display the details of each student. By clicking another page result.jsp is loaded with the details of selected student and there is also a link home to return to this page again. But this is not happening by clicking the home link in result page

Comment: I'm afraid I don't exactly know what could be happening :(

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll check further. I'm new jsp/spring. That I'm asking too  more questions. Thanks for your immediate response

Comment: @PramodPP No problem! Just trying to help :)